# Git Bash Error on split multiple text files : split: extra operand ‘DPtr3ltmwr3PI.txt’

Tags: split, git-bash

I use Git Bash on Windows 10 to split multiple text files. I open Git Bash in the folder with those .txt files, and I use this formula:

`$ split -b 500k *.txt`

And I get this error:

```
split: extra operand ‘DPtr3ltmwr3PI.txt’
Try 'split --help' for more information.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` to print all files and pipe the output to the `split` command

```
cat *.txt | split -b 500k
```

Comment: Works, thanks. instead of json extension I use for text files:   `cat *.txt | split -b 500k`

Comment: Yes, sorry I tested it with JSON files before my answer and forgot to update my example